# Why is it good practice to prepare western blot samples in pairs when you have two experimental groups?

Tags: protocol, western-blot

I have done some Western blots where I have analysed the expression levels of a certain protein in brain homogenates from wild-type and knockout mice. When preparing brain homogenates, I was advised to prepare them in pairs, so that on the same day two brain homogenates, one from a wild-type mouse and the other from a knockout mouse were prepared.

I know that paired analysis is useful for comparing differences visually on the blot between samples from two experimental groups. However, I was wondering whether there are any other benefits (e.g. for statistical analysis) to preparing samples in pairs for a Western blot analysis besides just ease of visual comparison? Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This point is not unique to Western Blot, but to any case-control study: if there is variability inherent in the preparation procedure, this variability will be reduced when the two samples are prepared simultaneously. This is perhaps easier understood using an analogy: if a toaster fits two toasts, but there is variation in the toasting time - the toasts that were in the toaster together are likely to be cooked/burned to the same level.

Statistically, one takes the full advantage of such improvements when using the statistical techniques specifically designed for [paired data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_data), such as [paired difference test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_difference_test) (see also [paired samples t-test)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Unpaired_and_paired_two-sample_t-tests). But even unpaired statistical methods are likely to show better performance (in terms of identifying significant results).